# Como faço para finalizar essa função ao clicar no botão finalizar?

Tags: javascript, ionic, typescript

button block ion-button (click)="getLoc()">iniciar

button block ion-button (click)="getLoc()">Finalizar

Quando clico no botão "Iniciar", essa função pega a cada 10 segundos a localização atual, como faço para parar de coletar a localização ao clicar no botão finalizar?

getLoc(){

```
                    var intervalo = window.setInterval(function() {
                      // corpo da funcao

                                  var options = {
                                    enableHighAccuracy: true,
                                    timeout: 5000,
                                    maximumAge: 0
                                  };

                                  function success(pos) {
                                    var crd = pos.coords;

                                    console.log('Sua localização é');
                                    console.log(`Latitude : ${crd.latitude}`);
                                    console.log(`Longitude: ${crd.longitude}`);
                                    //console.log(`More or less ${crd.accuracy} meters.`);
                                    // console.log(crd.latitude);

                                  };

                                  function error(err) {
                                    console.warn(`ERROR(${err.code}): ${err.message}`);
                                  };


                            navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(success, error, options);

                      },5000);



        }
```

Comment: Consegue colocar mais informações no código?

Comment: Já foi resolvido.

Comment: Então coloque a resposta para que outras pessoas que tenham a mesma dúvida saibam como resolver.

Comment: O botão Finalizar chama uma função  getLocStop() que vai limpar a variavel this.intervalo como a seguir:  getLocStop(){
          
            window.clearInterval(this.intervalo);
           

            
      
           
        }
        

}